# Used up all BitLocker recovery keys, what to do next?

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, encryption, bitlocker

I have been trying to install Linux alongside bitlocker encrypted Windows 10. All went well and I managed to get Linux running with Windows in dual boot mode.

During installation I had to disable UEFI secure boot in order to circumvent the cumbersome process of making Linux bootloader work with UEFI. When I disabled secure boot (prior to Linux installation) Windows asked me for BitLocker recovery key which I successfully retrieved from my Microsoft account and entered.

I then booted into Windows and rebooted back to continue the Linux installation. After Linux was installed, I wanted to boot Windows but was greeted with this message:

> There are no more BitLocker recovery options on your PC. You'll need to use recovery tools. Press the Windows key for UEFI Firmware Settings.

After Googling for a solution, I created a rescue USB and booted from it in order to disable BitLocker once and for all. I got into command line and tried to use `manage-bde -unlock C:`. In order to do so, I went to my Microsoft account to get a BitLocker recovery key. To my surprise I saw the following message there:

> BitLocker recovery keys
>
> You don't have any BitLocker recovery keys uploaded to your Microsoft account.

What?

I just saw two BitLocker keys there right before I used them. Does it mean that BitLocker keys **are not reusable**?! Why on Earth was it not communicated before?

So, here I am with my whole `C:` drive bitlocked. I backed up all my files so it is fine but I really don't want to erase my whole drive and reinstall Windows 10 and then repeat the Linux installation again.

What can I do now?

Comment: You need to re-enable Secure Boot... whether this solves the Bitlocker issue, I'm not sure, but if Windows was installed with Secure Boot enabled, enabled it must remain.  It would be best to take the time to correctly set up Linux to use Secure Boot, otherwise, re-install Windows with Secure Boot disabled _(which is not recommended since Secure Boot is there to prevent malware modifying the bootloader, Windows or otherwise.  **If something is worth doing, it's worth doing right the first time around.**)_.

Comment: That would have worked if OP _hadn't_ entered the recovery key the first time. Every time you do this, Windows reseals the TPM-stored key against the new state – and if Secure Boot is disabled it just fallbacks to the old mode of sealing against precise system configuration. There is **nothing** specific that would require Secure Boot to remain enabled forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What? I just saw two BitLocker keys there right before I used them. Does it mean that BitLocker keys are not reusable?!

They are. I've used my recovery key dozens of times while trying to work out TPM issues. The recovery operation is completely offline – the bunch of numbers directly acts as an additional password for the disk.

(Also, each drive normally has just one recovery key of a given type. If you had two, the other one must have been for a different system anyway, so even if it *weren't* reusable, it wouldn't have been used up in the first place.)

Make sure you're looking at the correct Microsoft Account.

> When I disabled secure boot (prior to Linux installation) Windows asked me for BitLocker recovery key which I successfully retrieved from my Microsoft account and entered.

Try to return the firmware to that exact state. Linux probably added a new NVRAM boot entry – remove it.